# Load XML to Neo4j

Tags: xml, neo4j, dataset, ontology

I need to load this XML file with brainstorming Ubuntu data in a GraphDB Neo4j. The analysis would be for my master thesis.
I searched any alternatives, but I have not been able to organize to import.

[Dataset](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5TeDj4ArYt1NE1fcjF5T1A4SFk&usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [xml2neo](https://github.com/moxious/xml2neo) which processes XML documents and produces a set of cypher statements that imports the data into neo4j.  From then, you can transform and query the graph as needed.

Answer (score 0):

[NoSqlUnit](https://github.com/lordofthejars/nosql-unit#neo4j-engine) has tools for loading / exporting to/from GraphML.